# What are the conditions you can include in the Array.from method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following code:`Array.from({length: 5}, (v, i) => i);`

returns the following array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Are there any other conditions you can include in the curly braces? (for example to change the value of the initial element or the step of the sequence)

Comment: The second argument could be any function, it works just like `array#map`.

Comment: See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from - the first argument is an *array-like*, which is why an object with a length prop works.

Comment: Yes, I went through that article but I haven't seen the {length: } feature before. I was wondering if it had a name and what the alternatives might be.

Comment: `{length: 5}` is not a "condition" it's an array-like that can be used to generate a new array of similar length. That's it. If you include a positive integer property which is within bounds (e.g., `{0: "hello", 1: "world", length: 5}` then you'd get that as the first parameter of the callback (`v` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

**Array.from** takes an **iterable** or **array-like** value and makes a “real” Array from it.

In your example **{length: 5}** is an array-like object.

Example of iterable object which can also be passed to Array.from:

```
let range = {
  from: 1,
  to: 5,

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    this.current = this.from;
    return this;
  },

  next() {
    if (this.current <= this.to) {
      return { done: false, value: this.current++ };
    } else {
      return { done: true };
    }
  }
};

for (let num of range) {
  alert(num); // 1, then 2, 3, 4, 5
}
```

For additional info please see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols
- https://javascript.info/iterable#symbol-iterator